# Adjusting CFWindow position on the screen, is it possible?

Tags: coldfusion-10

I try to use cfwindow to deliver an error/warning message to my users. It works but the only problem is the pop up window is off the screen all the way to the bottom sinking to the task bar.
I thought I can use the x and y attributes but I tried them and they did not work.
Is it possible to adjust the positioning of cfwindow at all so when it shows up it will be in the middle of the screen or at least in the middle up instead of sinking down below?

```
<CFTRY>
   <cffile action="upload" filefield="uploadfile" destination="#TempDestination#" nameConflict="overwrite" result="myupload">
   <cfdump var="#myupload#">
   <CFCATCH type="Any">
        <cfwindow initShow="true" title="Minute Upload Problem" center="true" height="200" width="400"
                  x="880" y="850"
                  bodyStyle="font-family: verdana; color: ##000000; font-size: 13;"
                  headerStyle="font-family: verdana; background-color: ##ff0000; color: ##ffffff"
                  resizable="False" name="NoPermission">
                  <!--- message --->
                  <div align="center">
                  Destination Folder may not be set to accept your file<br>
                  Please contact the webmaster.
                  </div>
        </cfwindow>
   </CFCATCH>
</CFTRY>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit the window as per x & y coordinates, you will have to set

> center="false"

If center is set to true, then it will take precedence over the x & y coordinates. I have set `center="false"`. Now, the position of the new popup windows changes, as I change the x & y coordinates.